# Any good, up-to-date advanced textbooks/handbooks in statistical parsing?

Tags: computational-linguistics, reference-request, parsing

I was wondering if there are any good, up-to-date advanced textbooks in parsing, after having finished the preliminary treatments in Jurafsky & Martin and Manning & Schütze.  Either constituency or dependency parsing will do, though I'm not interested in deterministic parsing. I have a background in statistics, though not really in computer science; however, I'll be happy to fill in any gaps in my knowledge as I go. Thanks!